# Iptables block incoming connections to network interface from subnet

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, wireguard, hostapd

I have a Linux machine that uses Hostapd to serve a WiFi hotspot. I also have a Raspberry Pi that connects to this WiFi hotspot as a DHCP Client. The Linux machine has a Cellular interface and shares this internet connection with the Raspberry Pi, using ipv4 forwarding in the Kernel. Furthermore, the machine has a Wireguard interface named 'wg0'. I can SSH into the Raspberry Pi from the Linux Machine and successfully ping 10.10.10.1, and the ip address of the cellular interface. I can **also** ping the Wireguard interface at 10.10.0.3.
[image]

What I want is to block the ability of the Raspberry Pi to ping the Wireguard interface at 10.10.0.3. I would like the Raspberry Pi to be unaware of the wg0 inteface's existence.

I thought I could block all traffic inbound to wg0 from the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet with the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wg0 -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j DROP
```

However, the Pi can still ping 10.10.0.3. How can I make the wg0 interface invisible to connected clients on the wan0 hotspot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do this when using *iptables*.

- Drop traffic to the host itself for destination 10.10.0.3:

  The packet enters from the `wan0` interface, not from the `wg0` interface. The source address doesn't really matter: Device 2 is already identified by the input interface. And just state the destination:

  ```
  iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wan0 -d 10.10.0.3 -j DROP
  ```

  It's not possible with *iptables* to do this kind of filter only with the `wg0` interface name without stating the 10.10.0.3 address because `wg0` will is not an output interface (there's no output interface for the INPUT path).
- Also drop traffic *forwarded* from `wan0` to `wg0` (this time `wg0` *is* the output interface):

  ```
  iptables -I FORWARD -i wan0 -o wg0 -j DROP
  ```
- And to be thorough prevent ARP probes to get an answer

  Linux follows the weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model) and also sort-of applies this model for ARP: by default Linux will also reply to ARP requests from other IP LANs and/or interface:

  > [`arp_ignore`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1646) - INTEGER
  >
  > ```
  > Define different modes for sending replies in response to
  > received ARP requests that resolve local target IP addresses:
  >
  > - 0 - (default): reply for any local target IP address, configured
  >   on any interface
  > - 1 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
  >   configured on the incoming interface
  > - 2 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
  >   configured on the incoming interface and both with the
  >   sender's IP address are part from same subnet on this interface
  > ```
  >
  > [...]

  So even with the address firewalled at the IP level, this address can still be discovered at the ARP level by running on Device 2:

  ```
  arping 10.10.0.3
  ```

  Using `arptables` or `nft` to firewall such ARP request would be overkill. One can just tell the kernel to change its behavior for the `wan0` interface:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wan0.arp_ignore=1
  ```

  Value 1 is enough, though 2 could have been chosen.